# Render a url as link with url itself as link text in typoscript

Tags: typo3, typoscript, templavoila

How to render a url as hyper link with typoscript?

Typoscript:

```
    20 = TEXT
    20.field = email
    20.Wrap = <span><a href="mailto: | " >Link text</a></span>
```

Above typoscript gives me the HTML output

```
    <a href="mailto:email" >Link text</a>
```

I want email it self in the place of Link text.
How to achieve this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Problem solved myself... :)

```
    20 = TEXT
    20.dataWrap = <span><a href="mailto:{field:email}" >{field:email}</a></span>
```

Answer (score 4):

```
20 = TEXT
20.typolink.parameter.field = email
```

This code will wrap your field with the standard [typolink function](http://wiki.typo3.org/TSref/typolink). If an "@" is found, typo3 will wrap it as an email-address.

This solution will parse your address with the useful [typo3 spam email protection](http://buzz.typo3.org/people/ron-hall/article/spam-protecting-your-typo3-e-mail-addresses-with-a-special-twist/)